# koala gem in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am making a rails site and I want to interact with facebook and get some photos from pages
I have seen this tutorial but it shows friends only
https://github.com/arsduo/koala/
I have made this steps

```
@graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(oauth_access_token)
profile = @graph.get_object("me")
friends = @graph.get_connections("me", "friends")
@graph.put_connections("me", "feed", :message => "I am writing on my wall!")
```

the question now is
how can I get photos from a facebook page by using koala gem ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have required access:

`photos = @graph.get_connections fb_page_id, "photos"`

[Facebook Graph Exlorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) is a good place to experiment.

Comment: this only gets the profile picture . I need all photos , there is some thing called fql but i don't know how to use it